# Why did Tony take off his suit in the Hydra base?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, while the Avengers are invading the Hydra base to get Loki's scepter, Tony finds a hidden passage, and then takes off his suit to explore, leaving it to guard the entrance.

But why would he take off the suit, leaving himself defenseless if anyone was in the room?